# Android Java Correct way to call Threads

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, completable-future

**Problem**

As a beginner in Android coming from Java and C# backends, I'm not sure how to avoid the warning that 'too much work is being done in the main Thread'. Since I'm already using CompletableFuture to make my HTTP calls, I think I'm not using the Main thread anymore.

**Things I tried:**

1. Ttried wrapping the controller as an AsyncTask(), but realized 1) is deprecated 2) got the cryptic error.

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
> Looper.prepare().

2. Tried to wrap the controller into a Thread

   ```
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

      @Override
      public void run(){
   ```

//Controller code

```
  }
});
thread.start();
```

But since it returns void, I am not able to get the result of the asynchronous operation once is finished.

**Current status**

Here's my current code, if you have time to take a look. Sorry about the non-English parts of the code, luckily these are not too relevant.

**Activiy Code**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SolicitarEnvioSMSConfirmacion extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_solicitar_envio_smsconfirmacion);

        cargarLogicaForm();
    }

    public void cargarLogicaForm(){

        TextView textViewMsisdn = findViewById(R.id.textViewMsisdn);
        Button buttonEnviarSms = findViewById(R.id.buttonEnviarSms);


        buttonEnviarSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickEnButtonEnviarSms(textViewMsisdn.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void clickEnButtonEnviarSms(String msisdn){

        new ControladorSolicitarEnvioSMSConfirmacion().callEndpointEnviarSms(this,msisdn);

    }    

}
```

**Controller Code**

```
public class ControladorSolicitarEnvioSMSConfirmacion {

    public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, HashMap<String, Object>> callEndpointEnviarSms(Context context, String argMsisdn) {

        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> futureRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms;

        HashMap<String, Object> mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        try {

            PostOkHttp okHttp = new PostOkHttp();

            JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();

            jsonRequest.put("msisdn", argMsisdn);            


            CompletableFuture<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> loginResponse
                    = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

                try {
                    return okHttp.post(Constantes.URL_SOLICITUD_ENVIO_SMS, jsonRequest.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            });

            futureRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms = loginResponse.join();

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(futureRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms.getValue());


            mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms.put("descripcion", jsonResponse.get("descripcion"));
            mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms.put("exito", jsonResponse.getBoolean("exito"));               


            if (mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms.get("exito").equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {

                new MetodoDialogoError().mostrar(jsonResponse.get("descripcion").toString(),context);
                return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(jsonResponse.get("descripcion").toString(), mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {

            new MetodoDialogoError().mostrar("Error interno de la aplicacion. " + e.getMessage(),context);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }    

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityConfirmarSMS.class);         
    context.startActivity(intent);

        new MessageBox().showOkDialog("TEST_SUCCESS","TEST_SUCCESS",context);
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Constantes.EXITO, mapRespuestaSolicitudEnvioSms);

    }
}
```

**Update 2022-06-02**

I'm back after [wasting days with the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading) (shows mostly Kotlin and incomplete Java code) and unable to get Garener's advice working.

On the comments Gardener suggested me [(changing .join to ThenApply to avoid blocking the UI)](https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/).

Without knowing any better, I ended up improvising a terrible hack using [this post](https://camposha.info/android-examples/android-executor/#gsc.tab=0)

```
public class ControladorLoginUsrExistente {


    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public void callEndpointLoginUsrExistente(Context context, String argEmail, String password) {

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                DialogoCargando dialogoCargando = new DialogoCargando();

                try {

                    dialogoCargando.mostrar(context);

                    PostOkHttp okHttp = new PostOkHttp();
                    JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();

                    jsonRequest.put("email", argEmail);
                    jsonRequest.put("password", password);

                    CompletableFuture<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Boolean,String>> responseWebservice
                            = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
                        return okHttp.post(Constantes.URL_ACCESO_USUARIO_EXISTENTE, jsonRequest.toString());
                    }) ;

                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Boolean,String> awaitedResponse = responseWebservice.join();

                    dialogoCargando.ocultar();

                    if(!awaitedResponse.getKey())
                    {
                        new MetodoDialogoError().mostrar(Constantes.MENSAJE_ERROR_CONECTIVIDAD, context);
                        return;
                    }

                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(awaitedResponse.getValue());

                    HashMap<String, Object> responseMapping = new HashMap<String,Object>();

                    responseMapping.put("descripcion",jsonResponse.get("descripcion").toString());
                    responseMapping.put("exito",jsonResponse.getBoolean("exito"));
                    responseMapping.put("codigoHttp",jsonResponse.getInt("codigoHttp"));
                    responseMapping.put("respuestaTransaccion",jsonResponse.getJSONObject("respuestaTransaccion"));

                    if (responseMapping.get("exito").equals(Boolean.TRUE)){                           

                        Log.i(null, "Login ejecutado exitosamente, abriendo Actividad datos de usuario...");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityRedireccionDatosPersonales.class);

                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        new MetodoDialogoError().mostrar(jsonResponse.get("descripcion").toString(),context);
                        return;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    dialogoCargando.ocultar();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    new MetodoDialogoError().mostrar(Constantes.MENSAJE_ERROR_INTERNO + " POSTLOGIN " + e.getMessage(),context);
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

I'm keeping this terrible working hack until I get a better advice from S.O.

Edit: The hack stopped working too. Added a little class to show a loading screen, as follows:

```
public class DialogoCargando {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public void mostrar(Context context){
       
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.progressDialog.setTitle("Cargando");
        this.progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera.");
        this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        this.progressDialog.show();

    }

    public void ocultar(){
      
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

This detonated a new error that sent me back to the beginning.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
> Process: xxx.android.xxx, PID: 25314
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void xxx.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
> at xxx.android.yobiapp.xxx.DialogoCargando.ocultar(DialogoCargando.java:27)
> at xxx.android.xxx.controladores.ControladorLoginUsrExistente$1.run

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: `join` is a blocking call and you are executing it on the UI thread since the function is invoked in a button callback.

Comment: Thank you by your response Gardener. I edited the question to show how I tried to run that blocking call inside a separate thread but was unable to get the Task result.

Comment: I believe you want to use `.thenApply` on the `loginResponse` in place of the `join` and provide the remaining code (after the join) as the anonymous function parameter - it should use the caller's thread which in this case is the UI thread.  The `callEndpointEnviarSms` return is not used so not sure what the intent is there.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion, but I wonder if it would then create an 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?

Comment: I do not see any network code in the code _following_ the `join` statement - but I may be missing something.

Comment: Sorry for disappointing you, Gardener. After days I'm still unable to get it working. The blocking UI problem is even worse because I'm even unable to show a loading progressDialog. I updated the question to show my failed attempts.